# Is there a possible way implementing Promise inside angular.foreach?

Tags: angularjs

```
 var sanitizedresult=[];
    angular.forEach(voteResult, function(value, key) {
      // console.log(value.poll_watcher_id);
      var param={
        id : value.candidate_id
      }
      CandidateService.getCandidatInfo(param).then(function(success){

        // console.log(success);
        var row = {
                    ballot_name: success,
                    vote_count: value.count
                  }
                  console.log(row);
        sanitizedresult.push(row);
      },function(fail){
        console.log(fail);
      });
 });
```

How can I  delay the iteration of the loop for it to wait the response of the promise

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wait for async function in loop to finish executing before next iteration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32740236/wait-for-async-function-in-loop-to-finish-executing-before-next-iteration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to write your own function to loop rather than using angular.forEach.

This is done using recursion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32740435/1147542)

Something like below:

```
var sanitizedresult=[];

 var processVotes = function(voteResult,idx){
        var param={
            id : voteResult[idx].candidate_id
          }
      CandidateService.getCandidatInfo(param).then(function(success){

        // console.log(success);
        var row = {
                    ballot_name: success,
                    vote_count: value.count
                  }
                  console.log(row);
        sanitizedresult.push(row);
        if((idx+1) < voteResult.length){
            processVotes(voteResult,idx+1);
        }else{
           //use sanitizedResult here -- maybe a function call
        }
      },function(fail){
        console.log(fail);
        if((idx+1) < voteResult.length){
            processVotes(voteResult,idx+1);
        }else{
           //use sanitizedResult here -- maybe a function call
        }

      });   
 }
 processVotes(voteResult,0);
```

Comment: I check the Linked you gave, how can i implement that code to my code
I'm just a beginner to this Framework,

Comment: the output said  that the candidate_id is undefined , just like my first trial when i replicate the code

Comment: can you print the voteResult object? what does it hold?

Comment: voteResult = [
     {
        candidate_id: 1
       count: "123"
       poll_watcher_id: 5
       precinct_id: ""
     },
   {
        candidate_id: 2
       count: "123"
       poll_watcher_id: 5
       precinct_id: ""
     }
    ]

This is the voteResult

Comment: slight miss in the logic.
instead of         
if(idx < voteResult.length){
            processVotes(voteResult,idx+1);
        }

try

if((idx +1)< voteResult.length){
            processVotes(voteResult,idx+1);
        }

Comment: I already fix the undefined candidate id , the problem now is the "sanitizedresult" is empty
what will be the cause of this

Comment: in the else part of the if((idx +1)< voteResult.length), call a function which will serve as callback once the processing is complete and sanitized result has valid values.
The reason why sanitizedResult may be empty is because ansyc call might not have completed by then

Comment: Thank you so much for the help @Maverick

Comment: no problem buddy.. (Hint: Mark the answer as correct :P)

Answer (score 0):

```
var sanitizedresult=[];

var processVotes = function(voteResult,idx){
    var param={
        id : voteResult[idx].candidate_id
      }
  CandidateService.getCandidatInfo(param).then(function(success){

    // console.log(success);
    console.log(idx+"Thi is it");
    var row = {
                ballot_name: success,
                vote_count: voteResult[idx].count
              }
              console.log(row);
    sanitizedresult.push(row);
    if(idx < voteResult.length-1){
        processVotes(voteResult,idx+1);
    }
  },function(fail){
    console.log(fail);
    if(idx < voteResult.length-1){
        processVotes(voteResult,idx+1);
    }       
  });   
}
processVotes(voteResult,0);

console.log(sanitizedresult);
```

There are no errors but still the sanitizedresult is empty what will be the possible cause why the "sanitizedresult" is empty