# How to have the foreach loop to wait for $http.get to complete before moving on?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach

I cannot seem to have the code to pause and wait for the $http response before moving on. Currently my code looks something like this:

```
var postAuthorCache = new Array();
angular.forEach($scope.news.posts, function(value, key) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(postAuthorCache)); //Keeps printing "[]"
    if (!(value["post_author"] in postAuthorCache)) {
        $http.get('/api/tumblr_primaryblog_name/' + value["post_author"]).then(function(response) {
            postAuthorCache[value["post_author"]] = response.data;
            value["post_author_pblog"] = postAuthorCache[value["post_author"]];
            console.log("NOT CACHE: " + value["post_author"]);
        });
    } else {
        value["post_author_pblog"] = postAuthorCache[value["post_author"]];
        console.log("IN CACHE: " + value["post_author"]);
    };
});
```

But when it ran, the console.log output is not what i had expected.

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
NOT CACHE: aaaa
NOT CACHE: bbbb
NOT CACHE: aaaa
NOT CACHE: aaaa
NOT CACHE: aaaa
NOT CACHE: aaaa
NOT CACHE: bbbb
```

The output that I was expecting is having the `console.log(JSON.stringify(postAuthorCache));` to run at the beginning, then after querying $http, it runs either `console.log("NOT CACHE: " + value["post_author"]);` or `console.log("IN CACHE: " + value["post_author"]);`. Afterwords, it should repeat itself by displaying the stringify for the array object again, and proceed with the `NOT CACHE` or `IN CACHE` log statements.

So the question is, how would the foreach loop to wait for $http.get to complete, before moving on?

Comment: Multiple ways to achieve this, but better to get an understanding of how you're actually going to use the values, since `console.log` message order is likely not how you want to use it? If it is, could you manually loop through the array, instead of using `forEach`, and just keep a running count of the current `index`? And only proceed counting `index` in the `.get` callback

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a possible way implementing Promise inside angular.foreach?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36997004/is-there-a-possible-way-implementing-promise-inside-angular-foreach)

Answer (score 1):

You need to cache the fact that you're about to do a query, eg:

```
var postRequestCache = {};
var postResponseCache = {};
angular.forEach($scope.news.posts, function(value, key) {
    var author = value["post_author"];
    if (!(author in postRequestCache)) {
        postRequestCache[author] = $http.get('/api/tumblr_primaryblog_name/' + author).then(function(response) {
            postResponseCache[author] = response.data;
        });
    }
});
$q.all(postRequestCache).then(function () {
    angular.forEach($scope.news.posts, function (value, key) {
        var response = postResponseCache[value["post_author"]];
        value["post_author_pblog"] = response.response.blog.title;
    });
});
```

You'll probably want to add some extra error checking though.  Also note that it's possible to get the responses directly in the latter handler without going via `postResponseCache`, but this is easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code -

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.post('/api/tumblr_primaryblog_name/' + value["post_author"]).then(
        function successCallback(response){
            deferred.resolve(response);
            return deferred.promise;
        },
        function errorCallback(response){
            deferred.reject(response);
            return deferred.promise;
        });
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this doesn't actually answer any part of the question. It's also redundant, since `$http.post` already returns a promise.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to implement using recursion to wait for each call to complete. check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36997004/1147542) .

Other way is to use promise chaining [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23932019/1147542)

Comment: this should be comment, not an answer.